# How to find Sutra, Shakha and Pravaras

Tags: brahmins, gotra, ancestry

My name is Lokesh Sharma and my gotra is "Ratna Bhardwaj". I want to determine my Sutra, Shakha and Pravaras. Could someone please help me?